# Build a graphical map of interconnected location points

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, dictionary, location

Given a list of interconnected points, with each point having one or more one-way connections to other points, how to build a graphical map of the structure?

To put it simple, I could have points A, B, C, with the following connections:

- From A to B
- B to A
- B to C
- C to B

But there can be much more points (A1, B1, A2, B2, etc).

It's actually a 2-d game map. I need this to show the current player location. Each point can only be connected to nearby locations. In fact, I don't even need to show connections - I just need connected points to be shown near each other. They can be represented as little alternating colors squares, like on a chessboard. Then I need a way to highlight a specific point.

Which algorithm should be used to create a bitmap of the map?

Comment: Do you have some restrictions in mind that you have not added to the question? otherwise would be too simple as put all point on circle and add line between them...

Comment: can the connections intersect?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - It appears that the OP wants to represent a [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph).  (Several graphical representations are shown there.)  While the nodes could be placed on a circle, the connections would need to be arcs to allow for nodes explicitly connected in both directions, e.g. A to B and B to A.

Comment: Don't need to be arcs as you can draw straight line with arrow(s) like -->-- for one way and -<->- for 2 way connection... Still would be nice to hear what LoveDotNet needs.

Comment: It's actually a 2-d game map. I need this to show the current player location. Each point can only be connected to nearby locations. In fact, I don't even need to show connections - I just need connected points to be shown near each other. They can be represented as little alternating colors squares, like on a chessboard. Then I need a way to highlight a specific point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [dot](http://www.graphviz.org/) tool which does graphical layouts of directed graphs.  I don't know a lot about the algorithms it uses, but it does a pretty good job laying out graphs to minimize edge crossings and edge lengths.